# SQL Update Statement for all values of column when value equals certain value

Tags: sql

How would I update all row values of a SQL table in a column when the value equals a certain value?

For Example (TableA):

```
ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC
---------------------------
a       | b       | c
a       | x       | c
a       | x       | c
a       | x       | c
a       | b       | c
a       | b       | c
```

I would I rename all `x` in ColumnB to `y`?

Comment: update t set c = newvalue where c = oldvalue

Comment: `Update TableA set ColumnB = 'y' where ColumnB = 'x'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is simple update:

```
update tableA
    set columnb = 'y'
    where columnb = 'x';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE [TableA]
SET [ColumnB] = 'y'
WHERE [ColumnB] = 'x'
```

Comment: This answer is identical in all but formatting to the accepted answer, and was posted first. Who down-voted and why?

Comment: @theo - This isn't posted first.. click on the oldest tab and check

Comment: I can see several reasons for a downvote: using SQL Server syntax while the question does not specify a specific SQL dialect (and thus you should err on the safe side and assume the ISO standard), and posting only code without an explanation (although in that regard Gordon's answer isn't really better).

Comment: @Prdp -- you're right. I could have sworn I saw the time-stamps but I must have been mistaken.